# SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) and mail sent successful but didn't get email

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to send an email using PHPMailer, and here is my php code

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                            
try {

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      
use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
    $mail->Username = 'abc@gmail.com';                 
    $mail->Password = 'password';                           
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            
    $mail->Port = 465;                                    

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('efg@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     
$mail->addAddress('hij@gmail.com');               
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');


$mail->isHTML(true);                               
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

$mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

and here is the result from the terminal when I run my php code locally

```
 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server:  (0)
 2018-05-08 00:13:48    SMTP connect() failed. 
 Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

when I comment out   $mail->isSMTP(); it said that the message was sent successfully, but I didn't get the e-mail
and I don't know if the problem is I'm running my code locally that I need to put it into XAMPP to test it, or there is something wrong with my SMTP configuration, thanks

Comment: You appear to have comments running over to the next line (such as `// Passing true ... enables exceptions`). Are those just formatting issues with StackOverflow? Because in your actual code I'd expect a syntax error.

Comment: yes that's a formatting issue